# Failed to deserialize an object having List using Gson

Tags: java, gson, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string into a Java object but I'm getting the following exception:

> The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@306a30c7 failed to deserialized json object ["93"] given the type class java.util.ArrayList

My main file:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s = "{\"intents\":[\"93\"],\"_id\":\"frequestQueries\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JavaObject a = gson.fromJson(s, JavaObject.class);
    System.out.println(a);
```

The class which should represent the JSON is:

```java
public class JavaObject {

    public ArrayList intents;
    private String _id ;

    public JavaObject(){
        intents = new ArrayList();
        intents.add(93);
        _id = "frequestQueries";
    }
}
```

I tried the solutions given on SO with similar exceptions but I'm not able to figure out the exact reason. I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756130/failed-to-deserialize-an-object-with-list-using-gson) but seems no concrete solution is given. My Gson version is 1.4.

Edit: I have updated my Gson to 2.8.0 and the exception went away.

Comment: Looks like it does not know the type of `93`; try `public ArrayList<String> intents`

Comment: GSON 1.4 was released on `24-Mar-2010`, and you're not using generics when you define your `ArrayList` - What version of Java are you using? Java <= 4?

Comment: I'm using java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting solution to my own question since many people using `Arraylist` in Gson deserialization like  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756130/failed-to-deserialize-an-object-with-list-using-gson) were suffering with the same problem. Just update Gson version and it will take care of `Gson deserialization` issue.